# XMLHttpRequest Preemptively loads json before eventListener click

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Currently learning AJAX.

I was testing out XMLHttpRequest to load json when a button is clicked, but it seems to preemptively load the json before any click has happen.

I've also tried using append(this.responseText) to see whether it'll append the json every time i click on the button, but that wouldn't work either.

```js
function loadDoc(str) {
    let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
 };
  xhttp.open('GET', "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/" + str, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

let run = document.querySelector('#clickme');
run.addEventListener('click', loadDoc(2));
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>posts</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

</div>
  <button id="clickme"> click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

i have the example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j2b1kcex/2/)

Comment: because you are calling it and assigning what it returns to the event listener.

Answer (score 1):

You're using event listeners wrong. By writing `run.addEventListener('click', loadDoc(2))` you are immediately calling loadDoc and then setting its return value as the listener. What you want is to set a function as the listener that will run loadDoc with a value of 2. So you can do this with anonymous functions, by making an anonymous function that calls loadDoc and setting that function as the listener:

```
run.addEventListener('click', () => loadDoc(2));
```

Comment: oh shoop, yeah thats right. Such a rookie mistake, i fixed it like you said